# Objective C syntax, iOS sample code

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I'm learning objective-C and I was looking at some sample code from:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/SamplePhotosApp_AAPLAssetGridViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-SamplePhotosApp_AAPLAssetGridViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8

I'm confused about this line of code here:

```
CGSize cellSize = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout).itemSize;
```

I understand that it's trying to get the itemSize property and store it into cellSize, but I have no idea what ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionViewLayout) is all about. Can someone break it down for me? Is there another way to write this line of code?

Comment: `self.collectionViewLayout` is of type `UICollectionViewLayout`. 
`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (note the `Flow`) is a subclass of it.

So `self.collectionViewLayout` is in this case of type `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, but is generally of the higher type `UICollectionViewLayout`.

Because the property `itemSize` is accessed, and this property only exists in a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, but **not** in a `UICollectionViewLayout`, `self.collectionViewLayout` has to be casted down, so it can be treated as `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and `itemSize` can be accessed.

Comment: This should have been an answer, but I could`t post one anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What it means is:

Cast `self.collectionViewLayout` to be of [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html) type. Then of `self.collectionViewLayout` get the `itemSize` property. Finally, save everything is a property of type [CGSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGSize).

I believe is a elegant and concise way of writing it.

Comment: To add on, the double sets of parenthesis allow you access object properties using the dot separator, in one line.